# Android Activity layout for voice commands

Tags: android, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I am writing an android application to accept voice commands from user and then respond to it with some text.

I want to design the UI like IRIS app as shown below, the central blue icon change color depending upon speech, also when the app processes command the round blue icon shows circulating effects around it.

Can you please tell me which layout/viewgroups to use for this and how to create a similar round button which animates/changes color with input speech ?

Thanks,.

[image]